# How to inherit and customize controller in Odoo V12

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to inherit an Odoo web controller for adding a new parameter for using it in the view but I'm not able to do it.

This is the method of the class I need to inherit for rendering the view:

```
class CustomerPortal(Controller):
@route(['/my', '/my/home'], type='http', auth="user", website=True)
    def home(self, **kw):
        values = self._prepare_portal_layout_values()
        return request.render("portal.portal_my_home", values)
```

This is the view where I need to add the custom field:
[image]

So this is my try and I had no error but nothing happens too.
My tried controller (I tried to put the declaration @route as @route() too):

```
class websiteContact(CustomerPortal):
    @http.route('/my/home', type='http', auth="user", website=True)
    def home(self): 
        response = super(websiteContact, self).home() 
        if self.env.user.id != SUPERUSER_ID:
            response['isAdmin'] = False 
        else:
            response['isAdmin'] = True
        return response
```

My tried view:

//The view portal.portal_contact is called by the view portal.portal_my_home

```
<template id="website_contact_template" inherit_id="portal.portal_contact">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='o_portal_contact_details mb-5']" position="inside">
            <t t-esc="isAdmin"/>
    </xpath>
    </template>
```

Someone know how to inherit a controler, add a new field and show it in the view?
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

[Controller](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/portal/controllers/portal.py#L133) Add your customise logic In this method `_prepare_portal_layout_values`.

Thanks